# Yet another question about the slowness of the Iceweasel browser

Tags: debian, iceweasel

Using **Iceweasel** since three years on my **Debian** (today Wheezy), I noted that the browser became very slow **since one month**.
The slowness **is not** when I open the application **but only** for the page load in tab.

```
Average time for loading: 6 seconds minimum, often more than 15 seconds  
Cache cleared each time I test
Motherboard with bi-proc  
Basic page style
CPU load less than 5%  
The Iceweasel installed version is 31.4.0
```

I tried several stuff but the phenomenon didn't disappear.

1. starting without the add-ons
2. stopping some processes
3. stopping all virtual machines (kvm/libvirt)
4. disabling ipv6

Several releases of Debian were installed since one month: does this probably explain that?
How could I escalate the problem? With wireshark?

Comment: Iceweasel is similar to Firefox, right?  If so, then you might want to open up the network inspector (Ctrl-Shift-Q) and look at what's going on in there.  That would be a start, at least.

Comment: oh very good idea ! I note that the duration for the first get is always equal to 6 seconds.

Comment: The heck?  That's not normal at all.  Can I assume that you're not having this issue with any other program that accesses the internet?

Comment: @lnkBlend: give me an aplication which is easy to test. I should check the response time of the DNS ...

Comment: `ping google.com` would work, but so would Firefox if you're willing to install it.  Actually, Firefox would be optimal, as you should be able to install it along side of Iceweasel and then test to see if the bug is affecting both of them.

Comment: I found the problem: the first DNS in /etc/resolv.conf is desactivated. The nerwork inpection was a good approach. But I don't know how to avoid this in the future. Do you know how long Debian wait before to ask the second DNS ?

Comment: I tested this out by adding a few different DNS addresses to `/etc/resolv.conf`, and the length of time that it takes Debian to check each one seems to vary but is generally around the six-second figure that you (experimentally :) discovered.  That's all I can give you, unfortunately.  Does the problem come back with a reboot?

Comment: The problem is solved by using another DNS address.